# How to add watermark in android widget EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

Please provide the implementation of watermark text in EditText widget of android,even after Googling it, but cannot find proper solution!

Comment: What do you mean by "watermark" ? You wan't to display a fixed text on the background of the EditText ? If so, you have to use android:background.

Comment: it's like "write your name here" when user tap/click on the Edit text then the watermark text will disappear and then user able write name in cleaned EditText.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If by "watermark text" you mean the text which appears in the field when it is empty, then use the attribute `android:hint="My Text"` in the layout or programmatically call `setHint( "My Text" )` on your `EditText` object.

Comment: Thanks but I got an error when I copy-pasted it. It says `Error parsing XML: unbound prefix`. Changing `andoroid:hint` to `android:hint` fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a layout make its height and width `fill_parent` and make background transparent and add a `TextView` as a water-mark in this layout.

I hope it can work.